# Copy to Output Directory doesn't seem to copy XLS files to my web bin

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've got a website setup which references another DLL project in my solution. In that project I have two extra files - a .LIC file and a .XLS file. Both of them are set to "Always Copy to Output Directory".

When I build the DLL project, the project's bin/debug folder gets the .LIC file and the .XLS file copied into it. However, when I build the website, only the .LIC folder gets copied into the website's bin folder.

Is there a reason that the .XLS won't copy into it as well?

Thanks

PS. Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with a console application in VS 2010.  I would hit F5 it would not copy the xslt file to the output directory, however, if I just compiled (without debugging) it would copy the file.